# Can I save login session of openfire

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

I am new in XMPP. I am making a chat app with Openfire and Smack API. In my app, when I open the app after closing it, I have to login every time with saved user in sharedPref.

How can I save the login session, so that I don't have to login every time?

Does XMPP give a session saving facility?

Answer (score 0):

XMPP client server connection is socket based connection and if user is not using the application, it disconnects after some time of inactivity OR it should be disconnected.

So on every application launch you have to perform the login again.

From your question, If you want the server to remember the user session and somehow resume it then it's not available in Openfire Server. However, such feature does exists in Enterprise Edition of Ejabberd.

Comment: I want  to customize the openfire server....how much time may it may take or is it possible.

Comment: It totally depends on your understanding of Openfire existing code. How it handles the raw xml packet, from which classes it's routed. Separate handling for IQ, Presence, Message packets.

Comment: I have known all about how Openfire route table and Session classes ...can you please any hint to make session resume plugin...how to do in right way